# Compare two .NET Array objects

Tags: .net, arrays

I am trying to compare two .NET arrays. Here is an obvious implementation for comparing arrays of bytes:

```
bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b){
    if(a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

A more refined approach can be seen [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2006/03/08/array-equals.aspx) (via Google).

1. What is the simplest way (using less
   code but readable) to compare two
   .NET arrays?
2. What is the most efficient way
   compare two .NET arrays?

Comment: you could also add an early out if they are reference equal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Kathy's approach seems a good one to me. I'd personally allow the comparer to be specified explicitly:

```
bool AreEqual<T>(T[] a, T[] b)
{
    return AreEqual(a, b, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
}

bool AreEqual<T>(T[] a, T[] b, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    // Handle identity comparison, including comparing nulls
    if (a == b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (a == null || b == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if(!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

SequenceEqual as mentioned by CMS is good, but due to its generality over `IEnumerable<T>` I don't think it can do the "early out" if the length aren't equal. (It's possible that it checks for both sequences implementing IList though, to check Count directly.) You could generalise a little more, to use `IList<T>`

```
bool AreEqual<T>(IList<T> a, IList<T> b, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if(a.Count != b.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The straight array version will probably be the most efficient - adding generality and abstraction usually hits performance, although whether it's *significant* will depend on your app.

Comment: Shouldn't the above code snippets have `if (!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]) return false` ? Did I just detect an anomaly in my universe :)

Comment: also requires a closing parentheses after the second 'if' statement.

Comment: @Jon Could you please explain what is the advantage of explicitly specifying the comparer?

Comment: @Sandeep: Suppose you want to be able to compare two string arrays for equality, but using a case-insensitive comparison, so `{"FOO", "BAR"}` is equal to `{"foo", "bar"}`.

Comment: Shouldn't the second code snippet also use `!comparer.Equals(...)`?

Comment: Also, these methods will throw an exception if at least one of the arrays is null, which might be wanted or not, especially: `AreEquals(null, null)` could be a desirable supported case (returning `true`).

Comment: @jv42: Yes, you could do that - or throw ArgumentNullException.

Comment: You should use ICollection<T> instead of IList<T> if you want to check the Count as it defines what all .NET collections should implement (arrays, lists, sets, queues etc.). I disagree with the null == null comparison though. +1 for the EqualityComparer

Comment: @Shelakel: I'm using the indexer of `IList<T>` as well. Why would you disagree with `null == null`? That's what most equality operators do in C#... making null not equal to itself would be odd in the context of .NET, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Using the indexer should be faster, unfortunately there's no shared ICollection like interface supporting indexers - guess the best approach would then to implement this for arrays and lists and ICollection and IEnumerable as fallbacks. Before the length check it's probably a good idea to do a ReferenceEquals. The primary reason why I'm saying null != null is due to nothing is actually being compared between a and b (no references, hash code, members, behaviour); if equality requires measurable value, then null != null.

Comment: @Shelakel: Yes, if you need to implement this for `ICollection<T>` there are other alternatives, but they're not required for this question. As for nullity, if `a` and `b` are both null, then those *are* references being compared... and that's all the information that's available. `null == null` pretty much everywhere in .NET. If equality "requires measurable value" then you probably shouldn't be using it with `null` in the first place.

Comment: I think it would better to change if(a == null && b == null) to if(a==b) so it checks both null and same reference. Two collection with same reference are always same.

Answer (score 49):

You could use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
string[] a = { "1", "2", "3" };
string[] b = { "1", "2", "3" };

bool areEqual = a.SequenceEqual(b); // true


string[] c = { "1", "2", "5" };
areEqual = a.SequenceEqual(c);      // false
```

Comment: This [page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal) has some performance information and claims that `SequenceEqual` is about 10 times slower than custom implementation using a loop. I wonder why.

Comment: The `SequenceEqual` method is not available by default, you have to use `System.Linq`. Nice to know in case you get confused (as I did).

Answer (score 9):

With the advent of .NET 4 you can use the method Equals() being provided by .NET arrays' explicitly implemented interface IStructuralEquatable. Then the code might look like this (I rewrote CMS' example):

```
string[] a = { "1", "2", "3" };
string[] b = { "1", "2", "3" };
bool result = ((IStructuralEquatable)a).Equals(b, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer);
// result evaluates to true.
```

(IStructuralEquatable is also implemented in Tuples (also new in .NET 4).)

Comment: or use `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Compare(a,b)`

Comment: Thank you Chris! Your solution has an important benefit over mine: it is null-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
static bool AreEqual<T>(T[] a, T[] b) 
{
    bool areEqual = false ;
    T[] result = a.Intersect(b.AsEnumerable()).ToArray();
    areEqual = (result.Length == a.Length) && (result.Length == b.Length);
    return areEqual;
}
```

I am not sure of the performance hit on this one though.

EDIT

revised version taking into account Jon suggestions:

```
    static bool AreEqual<T>(T[] a, T[] b) 
    {
        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }
```

Comment: If you can use LINQ and don't mind the performance hit over using arrays directly (and early out for differing lengths), SequenceEqual is the way forward.

Comment: This solution fails when there are duplicates: { 1, 1, 1} = { 1, 1, 1} returns false. It also doesn't take ordering into account: { 1, 2} != {2, 1} returns true.

Comment: "{ 1, 2} != {2, 1} returns true" should mean that ordering *is* taken into account, right?

Comment: I'm saying that ordering *should* be taking into account, but isn't. The two arrays should be seen to be different, but the original version of AreEqual in this answer returns true. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you want to check if 2 sets have the same unique values then maybe use something like: `return (new HashSet<T>(a)).SetEquals(b);` (this ignores order and don't care if the same value exists more then once.